# Automating Sign Up

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation

I'm trying to login to Amazon via the node.js `request` module, and seem to be having difficulties.

My aim is to login to the site via their form, here is my code:

```
    const request = require("request");
    const rp = require("request-promise");
    var querystring = require("querystring");

    var cookieJar = request.jar();
    var mainUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/";
    var loginUrl = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/ap/signin";

    let req = request.defaults({
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36"
      },
      jar: cookieJar,
      gzip: true,
      followAllRedirects: true
    });

    var loginData =
      "email=email@me.com&create=0&password=password123";

    req.post(loginUrl, { data: loginData }, function(err, res, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
```

I ran a debugger in the background, and found this seemed to be the URL called. I'm wondering if anyone knows what I may have done incorrectly.

Thank you.

Comment: have you checked their site accepts cross site requests?  Also would seem to be pretty unsecure putting username and passwords into a string in js like that

Comment: If you have a look at the request, they do seem to have them like that. When I watch the request being made from my browser, it shows it perfectly fine. When I try to replicate in code, it doesn't seem to like it. It gives me a 404, yet it works in browser.

Comment: Yeah unless they specifically allow it, you cannot make requests to other people's sites - have a google and read about cross site scripting.  The best you can do is figure out if they have an api and use that

Comment: Eek, because currently I use browser emulation, however I wanted a better and faster way to login so I turned to this.

Comment: Couldn't this be bypassed by going to the main amazon page then login?

Comment: depends what you want to do - if you just want to login to amazon and then continue on amazon's site, then why not submit a form directly to their page - why the need for any js?  If you are wanting them to return something to you that you can use on your site, then you will need to use one of their apis

Comment: The APIs they have require so much more, how would this be possible for me to fill the form in then? because the sign in code as above basically does the form.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is so cannot really answer, anyway we seem to be going in circles so good luck

Comment: My end goal is to be able to login to the amazon site via the form

Comment: so why not just make a form that posts directly to amazon - just copy their source code for their login form - why do it via js?

Comment: I use node for a project I'm working on